# php speedy or google minify - which is best?

Tags: php, performance, minify

I want to implement css and js minifier for my site.

So which one is best in terms of performance, flexibility and configuration ?

Comment: Check my answer for similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386279/javascript-minification-automatization/4386431#4386431, the approach could be used to help you finding the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement mod_pagespeed (assuming you're using apache). It's a Google apache mod designed to do minification on not only css and js but the html that is server as well (among many other improvements). The mod will minify, combine and cache (depending on your settings) on the fly when each page is requested for the first time.

[You can read more about it here](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2010/11/08/optimization-made-easy-with-mod_pagespeed/)

You can see a quick list of all the features it has here.

- Extended Cache
- Puts inline CSS into external files
- Puts inline Javascript into external files
- Combine external CSS
- Move external CSS inline to the html
- Move external Javscript inline to the html
- Collapse whitespace in html
- Combine headers
- Elide attributes (change `checked="checked"` to `checked`)
- Minify Javascript
- Move small images inline
- Remove html comments
- Remove unneeded quotes from html attributes (change `type="hidden"` to `type=hidden`)
- All of the above are customizable and can be enabled/disabled as required.

Answer (score 0):

I have used google closure compiler.
And it gives me the best minification.
But i have heard it can give problems with some browsers (namely BB OS5 and lower).

YUI should give no problems, and is the second best on the market.